# Android navigation component animate go back from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

The animation when I am going from a fragment to an activity is working fine but when I click back it returns without the custom animation I insert. The same if I make the navigation from a fragment to another with the same animations works fine. Here is the action code I am using:

```
         <action
                android:id="@+id/toTicker"
                app:destination="@id/tickerActivity"
                app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_bottom_up"
                app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_up_bottom"
                app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_bottom_up"
                app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_up_bottom"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122413117), you need to call the static [`ActivityNavigator.applyPopAnimationsToPendingTransition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ActivityNavigator.html#applyPopAnimationsToPendingTransition(android.app.Activity)) method in your other activity to get the pop animations to apply - it should be called directly following when you call `finish()` or as part of callbacks to `onBackPressed()` (which internally will call `finish()`):

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    ActivityNavigator.applyPopAnimationsToPendingTransition(this)
}
```

Updating the documentation to specifically call this out is being tracked in [this documentation issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79957185).

Comment: The first issue you linked is google private, normal people can't see it

Answer (score 0):

The previously selected answer doesn't work anymore.
[applyPopAnimationsToPendingTransition](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions#activity) must be called by overriding [Activity.finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()).

```
 override fun finish() {
    super.finish()
    ActivityNavigator.applyPopAnimationsToPendingTransition(this)
}
```